# emacs-custom file get overwritten

Tags: init-file, customize, load, custom-file

In my `init.el`, I have the following line

```lisp
(setq custom-file (expand-file-name "custom.el" user-emacs-directory))
```

which is supposed to set the file `custom.el` into `.emacs.d` config folder for getting all customization tidy. Over the years, emacs populated this file with various things.

I ran customization with `M-x customize-variable` and made some change and saved them. Afterwards, I discovered that emacs added the new custom into `custom.el`, overwriting the previous version of the file.

What's the mistake? Should I put `(load custom-file)` after the line above? Can this be the problem?

Comment: Please add that info to your question. Comments can be deleted at any time. Thx.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but you should carefully read all of `C-h v custom-file` if you haven't done that already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You used `M-x customize-variable`, edited the option value, and then ***saved*** it. When you save your changes they're written to your `custom-file` (or your init file, if you have no `custom-file` defined). So yes, it's normal that `custom-file` was overwritten.

Yes, in your init file, somewhere *after you define* the value of option `custom-file`, you need to *load* that file, if you want Emacs to recognize its customizations.

And it's generally better to use `customize-save-variable` or `customize-set-variable` than just `setq`, to change the value of a user option.  It's not critical here, but it's a good habit to have.

For example, in your init file:

```lisp
;; Possibly some stuff...

(customize-save-variable 'custom-file  (expand-file-name "custom.el" user-emacs-directory))

;; Possibly some other stuff...

(load-file custom-file)

;; Possibly some other stuff...
```